# how to get all the ads from ebay using api?

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to get all the ads from the eBay-Classifieds API, I have also gone through the documentation.

```
http://api.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/docs/pages/home
```

but when I execute this below URL which is given in the documentation

```
https://api.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/api/ads
```

it is asking for username and password, I have also created an account on

```
ebay-kleinanzeigen.de
```

but that username and password seem not to work.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific about error messages you receive?

Comment: Did you pass proper credentials? Eg: http://api.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/docs/pages/security

Comment: I am not sure because I have created an account on ebay-kleinanzeigen.de , but that username and password do not work.

Answer (score 1):

for the eBay-Classifieds API you need an partner account and user account.
Without the partner account you cant use the api.
https://api.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/docs/pages/intro

> Contact platform implementations for general questions or partnership requests.